# Problem to display a pdf from my JSF Portlet of Liferay

Tags: java, pdf, portlet, liferay

I use liferay 5.2 with jsf-portlet.

From the page I want to press a button to generate one PDF.
In managedbean i build pdf and I want to show it in response.

In a `ByteArrayOutputStream` named `outputStream` i have my pdf built with JasperReport.

I write:

```
   PortletResponse portletResponse = (PortletResponse)externalCtx.getResponse(); 
   HttpServletResponse httpResponse = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(portletResponse);

   ServletOutputStream out = httpResponse.getOutputStream();
   String filename="Pdf" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".pdf";
   httpResponse.reset();

   httpResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
   httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+ filename + "\"");
   httpResponse.setContentLength(outputStream.size());

   outputStream.writeTo(out);

   out.flush();
   out.close();
```

I do not see anything output! In jboss log i read: `IllegaStateException`....

What is wrong?

LOG

```
        11:03:19,716 INFO  [STDOUT] 11:03:19,716 ERROR [IncludeTag] Current URL /web/organo-di-governo/datawarehouse?p_p_id=1_WAR_Portlet_Datawarehouse_INSTANCE_D7s7&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=1&_1_WAR_Portlet_Datawarehouse_INSTANCE_D7s7_com.sun.faces.portlet.VIEW_ID=%2Fview.xhtml&_1_WAR_Portlet_Datawarehouse_INSTANCE_D7s7_com.sun.faces.portlet.NAME_SPACE=_1_WAR_Portlet_Datawarehouse_INSTANCE_D7s7_ generates exception: null
                11:03:19,717 INFO  [STDOUT] 11:03:19,717 ERROR [IncludeTag] java.lang.IllegalStateException
                    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripResponse.getWriter(StripResponse.java:85)
                    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
                    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
                    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:326)
                    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:342)
                    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.print(JspWriterImpl.java:468)
                    at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.includeVM(ThemeUtil.java:208)
                    at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.include(ThemeUtil.java:68)
                    at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:59)
                    at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portal_jsp._jspx_meth_liferay_002dtheme_005finclude_005f1(portal_jsp.java:816)
                    at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portal_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fotherwise_005f0(portal_jsp.java:788)
                    at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portal_jsp._jspService(portal_jsp.java:724)
                    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
                    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
                    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
                    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
                    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
                    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                11:03:19,718 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
                java.lang.IllegalStateException



        11:03:19,719 ERROR [[Main Servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet Main Servlet threw exception
        java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripResponse.getWriter(StripResponse.java:85)
            at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
            at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)



        11:03:19,722 INFO  [STDOUT] 11:03:19,720 ERROR [OpenSSOFilter] org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:521)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:409)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)




        11:03:19,722 INFO  [STDOUT] n.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)


        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripResponse.getWriter(StripResponse.java:85)
            at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
            at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
```

Comment: We need the stack trace of the exception, not just the classname

Comment: my alternative solution is one external servlet...
i tryed with servlet... work fine...
I put in session my ByteArrayOutputStream and after externalCtx.redirect(externalCtx.getRequestContextPath() + "/Download");
 
but is not a good solution...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file, filename doesn't work in portlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35334589/download-file-filename-doesnt-work-in-portlet)

Answer (score 3):

The only appropriate way to do this is by using the "RESOURCE" phase of the JSR-286 spec. Currently in your code you are in "RENDER" phase which is forcefully only allows "text/html" encoding.

In plain JSP, the tag would look something like:

```
<portlet:resourceURL id="/super-cool.pdf" />
```

Then in your portlet class you implement the serveResource(ResourceRequest req, ResourceResponse res) method and read call the req.getResourceId() method of the ResourceRequest and behave invoke your business logic (create your PDF) and subsequently write it to the output stream.

In JSF, I'm not entirely sure if this is even supported, which means that the only way would be to delegate the task to a servlet call. Look in JSF to see if JSR-286 Resource handling is implemented.

Comment: thanks Ray,
but I can't believe that ...from JSF-portlet in Liferay there is not the possibility to take a pdf ..
It's the same problem if I wanted to make a download ... any one zip file or a text ...


there must be a solution!

Comment: Ray provided the absolutely correct answer to your question - no matter if you believe it or not. There's no way that you can "just" get the servlet output stream from a portlet context. This will result in (guess...) an IllegalStateException. Imagine: While your portlet is rendered half of the HTML page might already be transmitted to the client, so you can't suddenly change the content type to pdf. Use the RESOURCE phase - this is exactly what it's been created for. Honest.

Comment: how can i use this <portlet:resourceURL tag in my xhtml page?