# spring-mvc (portlet): how to return a pdf file in open file dialog?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

In my `@ActionMapping` I create a PDF file for the user.
Now I was wondering how I can return this pdf to the user in the form of a save/open file dialog box?
I'd prefer this over showing a download link if the generation was succesful.

I'm using spring-mvc 3.0.5 in combination with portlets. But if anyone has some pointers for a normal application then I can probably figure it out from there.
For 2.0 I read something about extending a pdfgenerator class and twidling in the web.xml but since nowadays we just need POJO's....

---

Edit:
Code after Adeel's suggestion:

```
File file = new File("C:\\test.pdf");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        try {
            byte[] b = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            OutputStream out = response.getPortletOutputStream();
            out.write(new FileInputStream(file).read(b));
            out.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "users/main";
```

Answer (score 8):

You can write that file directly to your `response writer`, and don't forget to change the `contentType`. For example,

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=something.pdf");
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(pdfFileContentInBytes);
out.flush();
```

Well, I thought its a `HttpServletResponse` what you have, but its not the case. As you are working with Portlet, its a `RenderResponse` object. After searching over the Internet, I found few links which might be helpful to you in this regard.

- First take an example of [Lotus Form Server Portlet](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/forms/v3r5m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.form.webform.developing.doc/i_wfsws_g_portlet_configuring.html), its showing the way how to allow multiple mime-type while configuring the portlet using `portlet.xml`.
- Here is [Spring Portlet docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/portlet.html), its showing how we configure portlet using portlet.xml. It has an XML element about mime-type, see if you can give the value, `application/pdf`, there.

Another idea is to change your parameter to `ActionResponse response`, instead of `RenderResponse response`. I am a bit blur here, not sure what is your super class? what method is it? etc....

To me, it seems that the problem is allowed/not-allowed mime-types for the portlet response.

Comment: to add to Adeel's answer ..content type should be application/pdf

Comment: @Mahesh: I was just doing that :). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just tried that and I get: application/pdf is not a supported mime/type. But that seems to be in the right direction.

Comment: @Jack: Surprising! It is a valid mime type. Check this out, http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3778. However, try with `application/octet-stream` this should work. But I would still suggest to troubleshoot why the former is giving you error. We might be able to say something, if you share the actual code and error message, both.

Comment: Added some code. I'm using spring-portlet-mvc so I don't have direct access to a HttpServletResponse (needed for the setHeader since RenderResponse lacks that function (probably for a reason). And that was the actual error. application/pdf is not a supported mime type.

Comment: Mmh, just tried that application/octet-stream and I get ERROR [jsp:154] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: application/octet-stream is not a supported mime type. So unless that setHeader is required there's something deeper going on.

Comment: @Jack: See if this thread, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=264854, yields some idea/insight. Its a Websphere Portlet stuff there, BTW.

Comment: Adeel, the parent class is just Object. Just like with spring-web-mvc you just annotate a POJO to use it as a spring-portlet-mvc controller. ActionResponse and RenderResponse are just different stages. You may (not must) have an action before a render. Action is actually an action while a RenderMapping has to do with the display. I'll give those extra mime types a try when I get an opportunity. (bit swamped currently)

Comment: just gave it a try adding the extra mime types doesn't seem to have done the trick. I'll see if I can't find some time tomorrow evening to experiment a bit further with it.

Comment: When I find a way to do this I'll update this post. But it seems it isn't possible to do this using a portlet. (Which is a bit logical since a portlet is part of the page, not the whole page and thus has limited capabilities. But it would have been nice to find a way.

Comment: @Jack: See the first answer here, it is throwing some light, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361765/problem-to-display-a-pdf-from-my-jsf-portlet-of-liferay

Comment: The solution is to use Resource Service Mechanism if you are using JSR 286 or configure a servlet if you are going with JSR 168 Portlets. See my answer for both the solutions.

Answer (score 4):

in spring mvc, ResourceResponse response

```
response.reset();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setProperty("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" +"example.pdf" +"\"");

InputStream fontInputStream = request.getPortletSession()
                .getPortletContext()
                .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/arial.ttf");
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 40, 40, 40, 50);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
response.getPortletOutputStream());
document.addAuthor("XYZ");
document.addTitle("ASDF");
document.open();
```

Comment: setProperty() as a replacement for setHeader() in portlets - Good to know that this will work

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer after I worked it out for a little while:
[Serve PDF in Spring Portlet MVC Architecture - Liferay 6.0.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654568/serve-pdf-in-spring-portlet-mvc-architecture-liferay-6-0-6)

The solution is to use Resource Serving Mechanism from JSR 286. The `ResourceResponse res` has a `res.setContentType("application/pdf");` method so you can use it to serve any type of resources. If you need it to be downloaded as an attachment, then use this:

`res.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"attachment");`

Answer (score 0):

My code:

> ResourceMapping("getPDF")

```
public void descargarRecibo(ResourceRequest request,
        ResourceResponse response, PortletSession session,
        ModelMap modelMap) {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;

    String fileURL = "c:/intranetdoc/PDetalleLlamadas/file.pdf";

    try {
        fileInputStream = new java.io.FileInputStream(fileURL);
        OutputStream outputStream = response.getPortletOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.addProperty("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
                + fileName);
        bufferedInputStream = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(
                fileInputStream);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferedInputStream.available()];
        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        int aByte = 0;
        while ((aByte = bufferedInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(aByte);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        bufferedInputStream.close();
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: lol - sorry - thought that was a question - however few words of introduction would be nice