# ERROR: application/pdf is not a supported mime type

Tags: struts2, liferay, liferay-6

I am using Struts2 and Liferay for developing an application.

My `struts.xml` is as follows:

```
<action name="download" class="com.stp.portal.view.DownloadAction">
    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
        <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
        <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="abc.pdf"</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

I basically want to download a pdf file from the server. But I get the following error:

> 10:05:55,782 ERROR [**Jsr168Dispatcher**:38] Could not execute action
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **application/pdf is not a supported mime type**
>           at com.liferay.portlet.MimeResponseImpl.setContentType(MimeResponseImpl.java:159)...

Don't know how to resolve this. Would really appreciate someone's help. Really need this to be done.

Comment: which server are you using?

Comment: Which liferay version? Are you using `Jsr286Dispatcher`?

Comment: Liferay 6.1 . No, i am not using Jsr286Dispatcher

Comment: @AleksandrM, according to his Exception, he's using Jsr168Dispatcher

Comment: [See if this help; it is for Spring MVC, maybe it can be adapted to Struts2.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654568/serve-pdf-in-spring-portlet-mvc-architecture-liferay-6-0-6)

Comment: @AndreaLigios: `Jsr286Dispatcher` extends `Jsr168Dispatcher` so it class name maybe used in logs.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code seems like only `application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml` and `text/html` are allowed.
Source: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.liferay.portal/portal-impl/6.0.2/com/liferay/portlet/MimeResponseImpl.java

Comment: Is there any way to do it? I want to download a pdf file from server. I have already lost 2 days in this.

Answer (score 0):

Put `portletUrlType="resource"` to the `<s:url>` tag which you use to create download link.

```
<s:url var="downloadUrl" action="download" portletUrlType="resource" />
```

Comment: not working for me, same error

Comment: @user2594235: Just tested, works for me. Have you re-deployed your portlet correctly? Liferay tends to cache everything. Also which version of Struts2 and portlet plugin?

Comment: i hv redeployed the portlet, but still not working, i m using portlet pugin 2.2.3

Comment: @user2594235: You could try with latest version, but AFAIK it should work in older versions also. Are you sure that changes are reflected in JSP? Try to change some text and see. Also post generated url.